# Cannot mount hard drive - No /dev/sda

Tags: mount, filesystem

I'm trying to follow intructions found here (http://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi/how-to-raspberry-pi-file-server/) on how to set up a file server with the Raspberry pi, but cannot mount my drive. The error I get is cannot find /dev/sda1. When I look into /dev, I see that I have no folders /DEV/SDA. Why is that and how can I create them?

Comment: Does `tail -f /var/log/messages` part of that tutorial work?? Do you see anything that indicates the USB devices enumerating?

Comment: Looking at the messages log file I see some mention of USB Device detected but no mention of sda. Though what is also odd is that when I plug in my USB, my VCN which i use to connect loses connection and has to restart. Haven't modded the pi at all, completely new

Comment: I also tried creating sda1 using `# mknod /dev/sda1 b 8 1 ` it ran but did not return anything, and nothing was created

Comment: You lose your VCN because plugging the drive directly into the pi is causing a voltage drop which is equivalent to turning the power on and off -- so don't do that as it is *not* a clean shutdown or a real reboot (altho, of course, it instantly boots again when the voltage comes back up).  Either use a hub, or plug it in first.  If your drive is not self-powered like the one in the tutorial, you probably will not be able to use it without a power hub as the pi usb ports are severly underpowered (140 mA instead of the standard 500) -- might be why it does not show up.

Comment: " If your drive is not self-powered like the one in the tutorial," - @user2092586 : are you using a self powered drive?

Comment: yes using a self powered drive. Will try plugging in it before startup, and if that doesnt work I guess i'll go ahead and buy a powered USB hub and will let you know if that fixed the issue. Turns out the raspberry pi costs more than $35...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `lsusb` and see if you see the device listed.  Do not bother with mknod, if udev does not create the node you won't be able to.

As mentioned in my comment, do not plug the device into the pi after boot.  Plug it in before you power up or use a hub.

Comment: "do not plug the device into the pi after boot" - I can confirm this. Plugging in a WiFi adapter also caused my Pi to restart.

Comment: Thanks! I just bought myself a powered USB hub, plugged it in, and now I see the /dev/sda1 drive pop up. - Though strange - after I entered the mount command `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /media/USBDRIVE/` I received an error "Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened" and if I cd to /media/elements (not /media/usbdrive) I see my drive. did it auto mount?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, nod /sda or sdb or anything. 
It was a USB 3.0 and the raspberry pi was seeing it but not able to access it. I changed it to USB 2.0 and worked perfectly fine