# Not found external HDD with Raspberry

Tags: hard-drive

I've recently bought 2 HDD ([Seagate ST1000LM048 2'5 1To](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B01LY3Q201/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) and 2 [Icy Box IB-AC603](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B003VL357U/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1) (USB 2) to build a little & cheap NAS server with a Raspberry model B+ (tried with version 2 and 3), following [this tutorial](https://pchelp.ricmedia.com/build-raspberry-pi3-raid-nas-server/3/).

I plug the hdd via USB with the Icy Box on the raspberry and I try the command `fdisk -l`, result :

```sh
pi@worker1:~ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

[...]

Disk /dev/ram15: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 14.9 GiB, 15931539456 bytes, 31116288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5ccc5eaa

Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1       8192    98045    89854 43.9M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      98304 31116287 31017984 14.8G 83 Linux
```

As you can see : no `sda` nor `sdb`. Trying with `blkid` :

```sh
pi@worker1:~ sudo blikd
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="boot" UUID="9304-D9FD" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="5ccc5eaa-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="29075e46-f0d4-44e2-a9e7-55ac02d6e6cc" TYPE=   "ext4" PARTUUID="5ccc5eaa-02"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="5ccc5eaa" PTTYPE="dos"
```

Finaly with `lsusb` :

```sh
pi@worker1:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Same...

Even worse, i dont found `sda` nor `sdb` in `/dev/`. I've tried to format the two HDD in ntfs on my laptop, I got the same results.

As I see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5051/cannot-mount-hard-drive-no-dev-sda), I have to throw my two HDD ? 
That would be a shame... Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: The Pi probably is incapable of powering the drives reliably. Use a powered hub.

Comment: Look at the output from a `dmesg` command. That will give you the kernel messages it emitted when it failed to recognise your USB devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside, IMHO, you should be using `lsblk --fs` to learn what drives are plugged in or mounted (BTW, sudo is not required w/ `lsblk`).

But back to the problem at hand:

It could be power as @Milliways suggests, but I've had expected other flaky behavior if supply voltage dropped below threshold. You also mentioned you don't see the drives on your laptop, so that may further discount the "power theory".

That said, you should double-check the specifications on your "Icy Box", and the other devices you're using:

- Are the Seagate drives SATA III - same as the Icy Box?
- AFAIK, the USB ports on RPi are USB 2.0, but Icy Box spec says USB 3.1... WTFO?

If you're able, you should test the drives by connecting them directly to a PC; i.e. do the drives appear ***without*** the Icy Box?

The tutorial you referenced mentioned RAID drives... is that what you plan? If so, you should plan with some greater care; you will almost certainly run into power issues if you try drawing all the power you need for 2 rotating HDDs over the RPi USB port.

Comment: It seem the problem is the power, I've just plugin one and it works fine, I see `sda` (I havent try this, i was apparently tired)... I will buy a hub with external power source. Thanks guys !

Comment: @rsz: Glad you're making progress. Any thoughts on why you didn't "see" the drives when you connected them to your laptop??

Comment: Yes I saw the two HDD on my laptop it was not the case on the raspberry. I received new [adaptaters](https://www.amazon.fr/Adaptateur-USB-Sata-SSD-HDD-Auto-aliment%C3%A9/dp/B017A7LQNK/ref=sr_1_17?ie=UTF8&qid=1551862309&sr=8-17&keywords=Adaptateur+USB+2.0+%2F+SATA+2.5%22+SSD-HDD+auto-aliment%C3%A9) with two USB on it. One for the raspberry and the second to plug to a power source. Works perfectly now ! :)